# is it possible to add database table in the cache memory. if so then how can we select a particular row from that table

Tags: caching

while working with caching, i have a query that is getting data from a view and also that query is not follow the rules of "creation of notification for a query". 
so is it possible to cache that query result with monitoring facility.
2. then another one is that how to add database table in the cache memory.
if so then how can we select a particular row from that table.

End of my question.no need to read blow.
Edit:

```
The reason I am looking if caching large data(entire database, or lots of tables) possible is because database columns are encrypted,even for different rows with different IV vectors of symetric rijndael key. Thus SQL filtering is no option or indexing have no meaning. Also the application, actually it is a framework for cloud and busisness applications, is being designed as database independent as much as possible. You would suggest encrypt only some columuns of a table only that holds really sensitive information,such as email address or SSN, but that will make the framework non-standard and you need to write new code for encrypted columuns and for unencrypted columuns for each different application. If there is no problem with caching, then I can do all operations on object basis,dictionaries, linq etc. Ofcourse I have to sync database and cache.
```

I plan to cache all or most database tables (encrypted) in memory.

I'm working on a cloud based application and it will have 100MB SQL Server / MySQL limit that will be shared by different clients. (So I can group them by client when caching; and even create smaller caching groups depend on the business model)

I have had no idea; how much time it would take to SELECT * FROM for 100000 rows, or 10 MB, or 20 MB of data etc. to fetch.

I made a quick search but could not find any benchmark that illustrates, "roughly" duration to retrieve mass of rows.

My company is using a business software that is common to use in most small-medium size companies in modern world. It is said to be have active records everyday, and have only 20MB of MySQL data in 4.5 years.

I checked in MySQL Administrator and see that the largest table is inventory_movements and have 7MB of data with 45000 rows.

I used MySQL Query Browser and execute to select all records from this table. Software tool states that it took 0.4971 seconds. Now I think I have an idea.

Fetching all rows (only pure SELECT * FROM, no filters, joins) in C# .NET; from SQL Server database, of 7MB Data - 45000 rows would result in similar duration, right? I am still OK, if it is 2 or 3 seconds.

This way; at least I have an idea; if I cache 100MB data; it would probably take 5 to 30 seconds. (Data will not be decrypted during fetch)(It will be later decrypted in RAM when it is required to be)(I am aware of I loose most of database features. Queries will be based on objects in the cache) (I'm just started to think while writing this comment; if I succeed; I can even use xml as a free database source, cause I'm designing OR/M like functions for this application)

Answer (score 0):

after the long search in internet, i have found answers for this questions. we can save any data in cache using string values as key.and we can save database tables in our cache either separate rows or as single table object.but we cannot query the saved table objects from the cache memory.

thanks :)
baski.